# Sum and count variables while executing a left join

Tags: sql, sas, left-join

Example code--SQL within SAS:

```
proc sql;
  create table add_losses as 
  select *, 
    sum(bb.gross_loss) as gl format = comma15.2, 
    count(bb.gross_loss) as n_losses
  from add_startend as aa   
  left join LED as bb 
    on (aa.process_name = bb.process_name and
        aa.group_id = bb.group_code and
        aa.start_date le bb.first_loss_posting_date le aa.end_date)

  group by aa.process_name, aa.group_id, aa.start_date, aa.end_date
  order by aa.process_name, aa.group_id, aa.start_date, aa.end_date;
quit;
```

Example data and desired output below:

Table AA

```
variable 1  variable 2  start date  end date
AAAA        BBB         1/1/2010    6/1/2010
```

Table BB

```
variable 1  variable 2  Date      losses
AAAA        BBB         1/5/2010    100
AAAA        BBB         2/1/2010    100
AAAA        BBB         3/5/2010    100
AAAA        BBB         4/23/2010   100
AAAA        BBB         5/11/2010   100
AAAA        BBB         5/25/2010   100
```

Table YY (current output)

```
variable 1  variable 2  Date    gross_loss  gl  n_losses
AAAA        BBB         1/5/2010    100     600 6
AAAA        BBB         2/1/2010    100     600 6
AAAA        BBB         3/5/2010    100     600 6
AAAA        BBB         4/23/2010   100     600 6
AAAA        BBB         5/11/2010   100     600 6
AAAA        BBB         5/25/2010   100     600 6
```

Table XX (desired output)

```
variable 1  variable 2  start date  end date    gl  n_losses
AAAA        BBB         1/1/2010    6/1/2010    600     6
```

The problem is the current code creates additional observations. How do I keep the same number of rows and all variables in table AA while adding on the columns `gl` and `n_losses`?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Between clause for this type of condition

```
proc sql;
create table add_losses as 
select aa.*, bb.gl format, bb.n_losses
from
add_startend as aa
left join
(
select aa.process_name, aa.group_id, aa.start_date, aa.end_date, 
sum(bb.gross_loss) as gl format = comma15.2, 
count(bb.gross_loss) as n_losses
from add_startend as aa     
left join LED as bb 

on (aa.process_name = bb.process_name and
aa.group_id = bb.group_code and
bb.first_loss_posting_date between aa.start_date and aa.end_date)

group by aa.process_name, aa.group_id, aa.start_date, aa.end_date
) bb
on  aa.process_name = bb.process_name 
and aa.group_id = bb.group_code
and aa.start_date = aa.start_date
and aa.end_date = bb.end_date
order by aa.process_name, aa.group_id, aa.start_date, aa.end_date;
quit;
```

Comment: The above code still results in additional observations being created every time more than one row from BB matches a row in AA. Also, I appreciate the coding tip but 'between' does not specify if the date ranges are mutually exclusive or not....depending on this characteristic one would want to use either <= or < and it is not clear to me what between uses

Comment: Did you use the Group by and order by clause

Comment: between uses >= and <=. Do you need this? or dp you need >= and <?

Comment: I need >= and <=, so in this case it would work. And yes I have used your code including group and order by as shown above - it produces the same results as the code in my post.

Comment: can you check the edit now. i do not have access to SAS right now but i think it should work now. I don't think you can use * in select cluase, it is going to pull all columns from aa and bb

Comment: That is OK for my purposes here - I need to keep all the variables in table AA (and there are a lot)...in BB it is optional but does not hurt anything here.

Comment: Then you can try aa.* and you must also use all columns in Group By, otherwise you need to write in another way.

Comment: The code does not run but (see the group by line) but I think I understand what is going on now - due to data issues beyond my control, the 4 variables in the 'group' statement do not form a unit of observation (although I would like them to), so SQL/SAS encounters a many to many merge situation and is forced to create new observations. Your code with only the variables of interest in the select statement produced a set with the 'correct' # of obs, which was actually less than I have in my set AA due to the above issue. I can work around this issue for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google for an SQL tutorial--one that covers `group by` then aggregate functions `count()` and `sum()`.

I suggest the following changes:

- When using a group by statement, explicitly list the variables you intend to to group by (instead of just using a `*`) in the SELECT statement.
- Use the between operator for date comparisons as it is easier to understand
- Make sure that every column in your select statement is either part of an aggregate function or in your group by clause.

Sample Data:

```
data a;
  informat start_date end_date mmddyy10.;
  format start_date end_date yymmdd10.;
  input variable_1 $
        variable_2 $
        start_date 
        end_date
        ;
  datalines;
AAAA        BBB         1/1/2010    6/1/2010
run;

data b;
  informat date mmddyy10.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
  input variable_1 $
        variable_2 $
        date 
        losses
        ;
  datalines;
AAAA        BBB         1/5/2010    100
AAAA        BBB         2/1/2010    100
AAAA        BBB         3/5/2010    100
AAAA        BBB         4/23/2010   100
AAAA        BBB         5/11/2010   100
AAAA        BBB         5/25/2010   100
run;
```

Final Query:

```
proc sql;
  create table add_losses as 
  select a.variable_1, 
         a.variable_2,
         a.start_date,
         a.end_date,
         count(b.variable_1) as n_losses,
         sum(b.losses) as gl format=comma15.2
  from a
  left join b on a.variable_1 eq b.variable_1
             and a.variable_2 eq b.variable_2
             and b.date between a.start_date and a.end_date
  group by 1,2,3,4
  order by 1,2,3,4
  ;
quit;
```

I've used shorthand aliases in the group by statement as it's easier to write, maintain and understand. You could also explicitly list the columns using them:

```
group by a.variable_1, a.variable_2, a.start_date, a.end_date
```

Comment: See above - my code now includes this syntax but the original problem remains - the code creates a new observation for every match, when I simply want to append the summary stats to the existing table AA.

Answer (score 0):

A query like the following would give your result (this may vary slightly based on the db technology):

```
select aa.variable1,
       aa.variable2,
       aa.start_date,
       aa.end_date,
       sum(bb.sales) as sales,
       count(*) as n_sales
  from table aa
          join bb on (
              aa.variable1 = bb.variable1 and
              aa.variable2 = bb.variable2 and
              aa.start_date >= bb.date and
              aa.end_date < bb.date)
 group by aa.variable1, aa.variable2, aa.start_date, aa.end_date
 order by aa.variable1, aa.variable2, aa.start_date, aa.end_date
```

Comment: This looks helpful but I think the way I am setting up the 'create table' portion and specifying what datasets are AA and BB is not compatible with your syntax. Could you include how you would specify which dataset is AA and BB? Also I need to keep all variables from AA so I suspect the first 'select' part is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue here that causes multiple lines to be reported instead of 1 is the lack of alias use in the select statement:

```
select      *, 
            sum(bb.gross_loss) as gl format = comma15.2, 
            count(bb.gross_loss) as n_losses
from        add_startend as aa   
left join   LED as bb
```

The `select *` being not preceded by an alias, it selects all variables from aa **and** bb tables (by the way, you should have a warning in the log to reports some variables are already selected)

To avoid that, use alias to indicate which table is your source data:

```
select      aa.*, 
            sum(bb.gross_loss) as gl format = comma15.2, 
            count(bb.gross_loss) as n_losses
from        add_startend as aa   
left join   LED as bb
```